# $\int_Ef>\int f−\epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory

Show that if $f\in L^+$ and $\int f<\infty$ then, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $E\in M$ such that $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $\int_Ef>\int f−\epsilon$.

I can somewhat understand why this should be true - mainly by the definition of integrals involving $\sup\{\int\phi\}$, where $\phi$ is a simple function. But how do you go about writing a rigorous proof of this?

Comment: What is $L^+$? I don't like notation $\int f$ (my opinion), is this $\int_M f d \mu$?

Comment: I guess, $f\in L^+$ means that $f\ge 0$ and is measurable, and we have a measure space $(X,\mu)$ with $\sigma$-algebra $M$, and then $\int f$ is meant as $\int_X f\,d\mu$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the sets $A_n = \{x \in X\colon f(x) > 1/n\}$.  What is their union?

Consider also the sequence of functions $f\chi_{A_n}$, where $\chi_{A_n}$ is the characteristic function of $A_n$.  Does it converge to anything?

Comment: Clearly we have $A_1\subseteq A_2 \subseteq ...$ and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n =X$. I see that $f\chi_{A_n} \nearrow f$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore for any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N, f-f\chi_{A_n}<\epsilon$. But when we integrate the both side of the last inequality, the right handside does not neccesarily depend on $\epsilon$ since $\int \epsilon$ is not necessarily finite. Could you make any comment for my attempt? Thanks.

Comment: @ErginSuer: You're right that $f\chi_{A_n} \nearrow f$, so that the convergence is monotone. Do you know a theorem you can apply in this situation?

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thank you very much.